# Recyclerview not working when a Cardview is moved off screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show Firebase data in a `Cardview`. I created my adapter and everything... when I run the app it works fine until I add data into Firebase that pushes a `CardView` partially offscreen. This causes the app to crash.

Here is my xml for MainActivity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
```

Here is my Cardview design for the adapter:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:id="@+id/recycler_item"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
card_view:contentPadding="8dp"
card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">
<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:minLines="4"/>
```

Here is the code that matters in the MainActivity:

```
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    new GetDataFromFirebase().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    // Read from the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("text");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    System.out.println("connected to firebase");
            /*for (DataSnapshot alert: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println(alert.getValue());
            }*/
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(values));
        }
```

Here is my Recycler Adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter    extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<String> values;
    RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> values) {
    this.values = values;
    }

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
return new
```

This is part of it too
ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item,parent,false));
        }

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(values.get(position));
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return values.size();
    }

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView name;
ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);

 }
}
}
```

Crash logs

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.samuelford48gmail.copy_recycler_view, PID: 16837
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at com.samuelford48gmail.copy_recycler_view.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:42)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: please share your crash logs

Comment: I added it @Mr.Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataSnapshot's [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()) method returns an object of type `Object`:

> getValue() returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types.

So you cannot cast that object to an `ArrayList<String>`. There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to iterate through the `dataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method and get the corresponding data. And the second, since every node in a Firebase realtime database is a `Map`, you can cast the object that you get when calling `getValue()` to a `Map<String, Object>` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Now simply iterate over the map and get the corresponding data.

As a conclusion, you get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Because you are trying to cast on `object` to an `ArrayList<String>` instead of a `Map<String, Object>`, which is actually not possible and that's why this error.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the Firebase API, DataSnapshot.getValue() can return any of:

Boolean
String
Long
Double
Map
List
In case of your error it obviously returns a Map instead of the expected ArrayList.

To solve this problem you should rewind why you expect a List at that point and why a Map could possibly be returned. Maybe the fact that a Map is returned is an error already.

So to solve your issue simply change this line of code in your main activity from

```
ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) dataSnapshot.getValue(); //wrong
```

to this:

```
HashMap<String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue();

ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
```